# java alias vs refactor method

Tags: java, refactoring, alias

I have 2 methods

```
public static void a()

public static void calla() { ... a(); ...}
```

There are dozens call to each of them and I need to change calling only to `calla()` (which will call `a()` inside).

The obvious way is Solution 1 - refactor all to call `calla()` instead of `a()`.

But is there a benefit to Solution 2:
 change method `a()` to `aInternal()` and adding alias which will be called by `calla()`?

The benefit is that the change will happen only in 1 file and won't cause dozen of changes in different classes.

Solution 1: refactor all call from `a()` to `calla()`

Solution 2: `public static void a() -> private static void aInternal()`

and (?) create an "alias" method `public static void a(){calla();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasonable answer is to end up with:

```
private static void a()

public static void callA() { ... a(); ...}
```

By doing so you make your intentions absolutely clear, and you allow the compiler to help finding all usages of `a()`.

In other words: any interface should make it easy to do the right thing, and hard to do the wrong thing. So when you want that `callA()` is used - then make sure that this method is the **only one** available to be called. There is no point in having a **publicly** available method `aInternal()`. Worse: having `a()` and `aInternal()` around is a sure way to **confuse** the users of your API!

Beyond that: the fact that you make `a()` **private** already **expresses** your intent to make this an **internal** method. Thus: don't was "name space" for a pointless suffix such as internal. To the contrary: use names that denote the **functionality** behind the method - internal versus external can be expressed using the modifiers public/private.